# How can I have only two specific keyboard layouts in my system without 'us'?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, session

I want only two keyboard layouts in my system: `us altgr-intl` (USA International (AltGr dead keys) ) and `gr` (Greece), so this is what I've selected in System → Preferences → Keyboard → Layouts. However, every time I begin a new Gnome session (reboot, logout/login), the `us` keyboard layout is automatically inserted at the top of the list.

I created a small script called `fixlang` that ensures the desirable result:

```
layouts='[us    altgr-intl,gr]' # tab between us and altgr
key=/desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/layouts

active_layouts="$(gconftool -g $key)"
if [ "$active_layouts" != "$layouts" -o "$1" == -f ]
then
    gconftool -t l --list-type=str -s $key "$layouts"
fi
```

which I run on login.

However, this is a kludge. How can I ensure that Gnome does not mess with my keyboard layout selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably experiencing [bug #688936](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-applet/+bug/688936). It hasn't been fixed yet, but you could try the workaround in [comment #5](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-applet/+bug/688936/comments/5):

> I've finally found a solution for this:
>
> 1. Log out.
> 2. Click on your account, but don't enter the password yet.
> 3. A small bar with several drop-down lists appears on the very bottom of the login screen. You probably never noticed it before - I for sure didn't ;)
> 4. Select the correct keyboard layout in the second-from-left drop-down list.
> 5. Login.
>
> Fixed :)

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I repeated my googling, and this time I managed to reach the same answer as yours; hopefully 25 rep points will compensate you for my inadequacy :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not running some script which is modifying the list of layouts on boot/login already? I've used only the "USA Dvorak International" and "Norway" layouts since 8.04, and I've never seen this. Or if you modified the GNOME settings files by hand (which looks likely, considering `fixlang`), this is probably detected and overridden on GNOME shutdown/startup.

Comment: Like I said, I modified the settings through the proper interface; and I don't have any other script touching the settings. I created `fixlang` to deal with this specific issue. Thanks for answering, anyway.